# Converting the endianness type of an already existing binary file

Tags: python, endianness, data-conversion

I have a binary file on my PC that contains data in big-endian. The file contains around 121 MB.
The problem is I would like to convert the data into little-endian with a python script.

What is currently giving me headaches is the fact that I don't know how to convert an entire file. If I would have a short hex string I could simply use struct.pack to convert it into little-endian but if I see this correctly I can't give struct.pack a binary file as input.

Is there an other function/utility that I can use to do that or how should my approach look like?

Answer (score 0):

We need a document or knowledge of the file's exact structure.

Suppose that there is a 4 byte file. If this file has just a int, we need to flip that. But if it is a combination of 4 char, we should leave it as it be.

Above all, you should find the structure. Then we can talk about the translation. I think there is no translation tools to support general data, but you need to parse that binary file following the structure.

Comment: Ok, the file does not contain just an int. It's a combination of chars. I dumped the content of a NAND flash and that is what the file contains.